# Text align to right and bottom of another text

Tags: android, android-layout

Excuse my next picture, done in a hurry :):

[image]

Please can anybody tell me how can I use Layouts and TextViews in Android to get something similar with I draw.
The box with one TEXT is a String and also the box with TEXT TEXT TEXT is a String.

Thank you.

Comment: how? I am using RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1):

I don't thing you can use 2 TextView instances for this situation. A workaround could be to use only one TextView and do your text formatting programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

In the RelativeLayout, inside each TextView tag use these attributes as per your requirement

```
android:layout_below="Id of the TextView"
android:layout_above="Id of the TextView"
android:layout_toLeftOf="Id of the TextView"
android:layout_toRightOf="Id of the TextView"
```

Comment: Tried all kind of combinations but I can not get to the result from the image.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do the trick. The keys are `layout_below` and `layout_toRightOf`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/LeftTextView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:paddingRight="10dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp"
         android:text="HI">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/WholeTextView"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_below="@id/LeftTextView"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/LeftTextView">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, that's a bad approach even if it works. I would suggest use a different textview for the bottom row. It may work with some combination in Relative Layout, but it may probably not be the same in each and every screen/resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [compound drawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)?

textview2.setCompoundDrawables(textview1, null, null, null);